# 2sxc Action method not found

Tags: c#, 2sxc

I'm trying to fiddle with custom controller features, and I'm having some trouble with actions not beeing found.

Wonder if this is a bad implementation on my part, a custom API limitation (there is not much documentation on the mather), or just bad code, so any help is welcome.

https://pasteboard.co/GViL7Ws.jpg

JS:

```
$2sxc(@Dnn.Module.ModuleID).webApi.post('hash/HashPassword', "myPassword");
```

Controller:

```
using DotNetNuke.Security;
using DotNetNuke.Web.Api;
using System.Web.Http;
using ToSic.SexyContent.WebApi;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Security.Cryptography;

public class hashController : SxcApiController
{
    public const int SaltByteSize = 24;
    public const int HashByteSize = 20;
    public const int Pbkdf2Iterations = 1000;
    public const int IterationIndex = 0;
    public const int SaltIndex = 1;
    public const int Pbkdf2Index = 2;

    [HttpPost]
    [DnnModuleAuthorize(AccessLevel = SecurityAccessLevel.Anonymous)]
    public static string HashPassword(string password)
    {
        var cryptoProvider = new RNGCryptoServiceProvider();
        byte[] salt = new byte[SaltByteSize];
        cryptoProvider.GetBytes(salt);

        var hash = GetPbkdf2Bytes(password, salt, Pbkdf2Iterations, HashByteSize);
        return Pbkdf2Iterations + ":" +
               Convert.ToBase64String(salt) + ":" +
               Convert.ToBase64String(hash);
    }

    [DnnModuleAuthorize(AccessLevel = SecurityAccessLevel.Anonymous)]
    private static byte[] GetPbkdf2Bytes(string password, byte[] salt, int iterations, int outputBytes)
    {
        var pbkdf2 = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(password, salt);
        pbkdf2.IterationCount = iterations;
        return pbkdf2.GetBytes(outputBytes);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed after a few atempts:

JS

```
$2sxc(@Dnn.Module.ModuleID).webApi.post('hash/HashPassword', {password: myPassword})
```

Controller:

```
using DotNetNuke.Security;
using DotNetNuke.Web.Api;
using System.Web.Http;
using ToSic.SexyContent.WebApi;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Security.Cryptography;

public class hashController : SxcApiController
{
    public const int SaltByteSize = 24;
    public const int HashByteSize = 20;
    public const int Pbkdf2Iterations = 1000;
    public const int IterationIndex = 0;
    public const int SaltIndex = 1;
    public const int Pbkdf2Index = 2;

    [HttpPost]
    [DnnModuleAuthorize(AccessLevel = SecurityAccessLevel.Anonymous)]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public dynamic HashPassword(string password)
    {
        var cryptoProvider = new RNGCryptoServiceProvider();
        byte[] salt = new byte[SaltByteSize];
        cryptoProvider.GetBytes(salt);

        var hash = GetPbkdf2Bytes(password, salt, Pbkdf2Iterations, HashByteSize);
        return Pbkdf2Iterations + ":" +
               Convert.ToBase64String(salt) + ":" +
               Convert.ToBase64String(hash);
    }

    [DnnModuleAuthorize(AccessLevel = SecurityAccessLevel.Anonymous)]
    private static byte[] GetPbkdf2Bytes(string password, byte[] salt, int iterations, int outputBytes)
    {
        var pbkdf2 = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(password, salt);
        pbkdf2.IterationCount = iterations;
        return pbkdf2.GetBytes(outputBytes);
    }
}
```